# Can Websocket server have multiple WebSocket client? Server: Java , Clients : C# and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, c#, websocket, client-server

There is WS in Java and there are client in C# and Javascript , basically First question is can we connect two clients to one server in Websocket and also is there any method to have handshake between client and server in C# and Java ?

I have tried connecting them individually but one connection is depended on response from other connection, any way to help with that

Comment: 1. Multiple connection is supported.

Comment: 2. you can handle message via OnMessage on serverside, after that, you can send message to client using websocketsession which is connected.

Comment: because of this is not a source code answer, I write a comment as answer :)

Comment: @Arphile Thank you for the suggestion I will try the websocketsession and update if that works .. thank you for the help :)

Comment: Hope it works @Pmax :)